How do I solve this equation involving a complicated fraction?
I was looking at a contest practice, and I came across this really complex looking fraction which states the following, how do I simplify the following?
$$\left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}}}}}}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3+\frac{3}{4+\frac{4}{5+\frac{6}{x}}}}}}\right)^{2}=100.$$
I first tried to solve the nested equation on the top as I understand this concept.
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}}}}$$
I first started by looking at the innermost term, $1+\frac{1}{x}$, and simplified it to $\frac{x+1}{x}$ Then, when I looked at the $1$ in the numerator, I got $1+\frac{x}{x+1}$ When I multiplied, I simplified it to $\frac{2x+1}{x+1}$. Then, I repeated the same procedure, and eventually got the answer of $$\frac{8x+5}{13x+8}.$$
But the issue is solving the huge fraction on the denominator, I don't know how to solve it. Can someone help continue the remaining part of the equation, or at least give a different approch to this?
I DO NOT WANT A GRAPH AS A SOLUTION

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D

It seems the solutions don't look good https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+it+%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7B1%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%2B%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B3%2B%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B4%2B%5Cfrac%7B4%7D%7B5%2B%5Cfrac%7B6%7D%7Bx%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%7D%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%3D100+

Is it a multiple choice problem? If so, you might be able to get a sufficiently close approximation by replacing the finite continued fractions with corresponding infinite continued fractions, and evaluating each infinite continued fraction. (I haven't tried doing this, however. This just a quick comment while I'm waiting for something to thaw out in my microwave oven.)

@RobPratt I do not think that the tag [tag:continued-fractions] is appropriate here.  The expressions involved in this problem are not continued fractions (continued fractions being the result of an infinite iterative process), and it is not at all clear that the techniques used in the analysis of continued fractions are appropriate here .

@DaveL.Renfro unfortunately there is no multiple choice answer

@XanderHenderson Continued fractions can be finite or infinite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction

@RobPratt The more salient point was that "is not at all clear that the techniques used in the analysis of continued fractions are appropriate here".  Tags should focus on what the question is about, and not what things might incidentally appear in the question.  This question is not about continued fractions---it just happens to involve an expression which looks like a continued fraction.

All the numbers in your last fraction are Fibonacci numbers...

Thats an interesting observation!

Please do not use the comments to answer the question.

It's a matter of ploughing through the routine algebra. Work from bottom to top:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}}}}}}
{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3+\frac{3}{4+\frac{4}{5+\frac{6}{x}}}}}}
&=&
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{x}{x+1}}}}}}}
{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3+\frac{3}{4+\frac{4x}{5x+6}}}}}\\
&=&
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{x+1}{2x+1}}}}}}
{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3+\frac{15x+18}{24x+24}}}}\\
&=&
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{2x+1}{3x+2}}}}}
{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{48x+48}{87x+90}}}\\
&=&
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{3x+2}{5x+3}}}}
{1+\frac{87x+90}{222x+228}}\\
&=&
\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac{5x+3}{8x+5}}}
{\frac{309x+318}{222x+228}}\\
&=&
\frac{\frac{8x+5}{13x+8}}
{\frac{103x+106}{74x+76}}\\
&=&
\frac{(74x+76)(8x+5)}{(103x+106)(13x+8)}
\end{eqnarray}
Plugging this back into the original equation yields
$$\left(\frac{(74x+76)(8x+5)}{(103x+106)(13x+8)}\right)^2=100,$$
or equivalently
$$\frac{(74x+76)(8x+5)}{(103x+106)(13x+8)}=\pm10.$$
Clearing denominators yields
$$(74x+76)(8x+5)=\pm10(103x+106)(13x+8),$$
and now expanding and rearranging yields two quadratics:
$$12798x^2+21042x+8100=0,$$
$$13982x^2+22998x+8860=0,$$
which I'm sure you know how to solve.

The expression inside $(\;)^2$ is the product
$F(x)=K(1/x)L(6/x)$ of two Möbius maps $K$ and $L$ where
$$K(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}}}}}=K(1/x)=\frac{a(1/x)+b}{c(1/x)+d}$$
and
$$L(x)=\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{2}{3+\frac{3}{4+\frac{4}{5+\frac{6}{x}}}}}}=L(6/x)=\frac{p(6/x)+r}{q(6/x)+s}
$$
where the matrix  $A_K=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ associated to $M$ is obtained by
$$A_K=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}^6=\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 8\\ 8 & 13\end{pmatrix}$$
and the matrix $A_L=\begin{pmatrix} p & r\\ q &  s\end{pmatrix}$ associated to $L$ is obtained by
$$A_L=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1& 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1& 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2\\ 1& 3\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 3\\ 1& 4\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 4\\ 1& 5\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix} 38 & 222\\ 53& 309\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence
$$F(x)=\frac{5+8x}{8+13x}\,\frac{228+222x}{318+309x}=\frac{5+8x}{8+13x}\,\frac{76+74x}{106+103x}$$
No, it seems that your problem reduces to solving the equations
$F(x)=10$ and $F(x)=-10$

Möbius functions are used in the study of continued fractions and in the study of certain type of conformal maps in Complex Analysis. In both applications, one is interested in composing maps of the form
$L(x)=\frac{px +r}{qx+s}$ and $G(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$. Clearly $L\circ G(x)$ is also of the form $\frac{\alpha x+\beta}{\delta x+\kappa}$. The components $\alpha,\beta,\delta, \kappa$  can be obtained by matrix multiplication. First notice that
$$L(G(x))=\frac{(pa+rc)x+pb+rd}{(qa+sc)x+qb+sd}$$
Associate the matrix $A_L=\begin{pmatrix} p & r\\ q & s\end{pmatrix}$ to $L$ and the matrix $A_G=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & c\end{pmatrix}$ to $G$. Notice that the composition $L\circ G$ is also a Möbius map and that its constant terms are given by
$$A_LA_g=\begin{pmatrix}  pa + rc & pb+rd\\ qa+sc & qb+sd\end{pmatrix}$$
